# Using R how do I add superscript in a title in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, superscript

I've looked through some other threads and tried using `expression` and `bquote` but without any luck. I'm a beginner with R and would appreciate help with this specific example. I've found the following code on another website and it is working for me, but I can't make the 2 in R2 a superscript.

**This is the initial code:**

```
ggplotRegression <- function (fit) {

require(ggplot2)

ggplot(fit$model, aes_string(x = names(fit$model)[2], y = names(fit$model)[1])) + 
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm") +
    labs(title = paste("R2 = ",signif(summary(fit)$r.squared, 5),
                     "Intercept =",signif(fit$coef[[1]],5 ),
                     " Slope =",signif(fit$coef[[2]], 5),
                     " P =",signif(summary(fit)$coef[2,4], 5)))
}

ggplotRegression(lm(TOA_NDVI ~ Field_NDVI, data = NDVI_type))
```

**This is one of the things I've tried:**

```
ggplotRegression <- function (fit) {

require(ggplot2)

ggplot(fit$model, aes_string(x = names(fit$model)[2], y = names(fit$model)[1])) + 
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm") +
    labs(title = paste(expression("R^2 *="),signif(summary(fit)$r.squared, 5)),
                     "Intercept =",signif(fit$coef[[1]],5 ),
                     " Slope =",signif(fit$coef[[2]], 5),
                     " P =",signif(summary(fit)$coef[2,4], 5)))
}

ggplotRegression(lm(TOA_NDVI ~ Field_NDVI, data = NDVI_type))
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In the future, it is good practice to provide a reproducible dataset so others can debug your question. For example, if you run `dput(NDVI_type)` and paste the output in your question, others can easily access your data and run your code. As it is now, nobody can run this without having your data already.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I will do this in future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "bquote". Here is the code:

```r
ggplotRegression <- function (fit) {
  
  require(ggplot2)
  
  ggplot(fit$model, aes_string(x = names(fit$model)[2], y = names(fit$model)[1])) + 
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm") +
    labs(title = bquote(R^2== .(signif(summary(fit)$r.squared, 5))~
                          "Intercept = "~ .(signif(fit$coef[[1]],5 )) ~
                          " Slope = "~ .(signif(fit$coef[[2]], 5)) ~
                          " P = "~ .(signif(summary(fit)$coef[2,4], 5)) ))
}

ggplotRegression(lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars))
```

Here is the generated plot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Amin, that's exactly what I was trying to do.